# inf or sup of a sequence including $(-1)^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

find $infA$ where $A=\{(-1)^n(1-\frac{1}{n}), n=1,2,3,...\}$
My work is as below:
if n is even : claim : $infA=\frac{1}{2}$
if n is odd : claim : $infA=-1$
Now should I choose the lowest number for the final claim?( and the greatest  if it was asking for Sup(A)?).
Now let claim $infA=-1$
1- I prove -1 is a lower bound for A:
$\frac{1}{n}<1$ so $-\frac{1}{n}>-1>-2$ from here $1-\frac{1}{n}>1-2=-1$ 
hence all elements of A are greater than -1, hence -1 in a lower bound for A.
2- Now I want to prove there can not be any number greater than -1 which is a lower bound. or equivalently I want to show $-1+\epsilon$ can not be a lower bound.
I do not know I think I am confused. I guess I know hoe to prove sup lim questions. I do not know how $A=\{(-1)^n$ affect the problem. 
I would appreciate your help.

Comment: There is no different $A$'s for different $n$, in particular for even or odd $n$. There is one $A$, with elements $A=\{(-1)^n(1-\frac1n)$ where $n=1,2,3,...\}$, and there is only one $\inf$. It seems you think (correctly) $A=E\cup O$ where $E$ goes with even $n$, and $O$ goes with odd $n$. Then you could talk about $\inf E$ and about $\inf O$ separately.

Comment: Yes to your first question. They are asking you for the infimum for the set, so you must take the infimum of the two numbers you obtain since your arbitrary splitting into odd and even cases only tells you the infimum for disjoint subsets.

To show that $-1+\epsilon$ cannot be a lower bound, try to find an element in your set which $-1+\epsilon$ is greater than.

Comment: If it helps, let $a_n = (-1)^n\left(1-\frac1n\right)$ and note that $$A = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{a_{2n}\} \cup \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{a_{2n-1}\}. $$

Comment: Hint: You can always find some $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$

Answer (score 1):

The infimum of a set is unique.

I get the point of your idea, but if you want to write it down like that, you should split $A$ into the two sets consisting of even and odd positiv integers. Then $A$ is the disjoint union of these sets.

However, this is not really necessary. 
But you are absolutly right. Indeed we have $\operatorname{inf}(A)=-1$.

For that we show that $-1$ is a lower bound of $A$ and the greatest lower bound.

> -1 is lower bound of $A$

We have to show that $-1\leq a$ for every $a\in A$.

We seperate the cases.
Either $a=1-\frac1m$ for some even $m\in\mathbb{N}$, or $a=-1+\frac1m$ for some odd $m\in\mathbb{N}$

In the first case it is clear, since $-1\leq 1-\frac{1}m\Leftrightarrow \frac1m\leq 2\Leftrightarrow 1\leq 2m$, which is true, as $m\geq 1$

In the second case we have $-1\leq -1+\frac1m\Leftrightarrow 0\leq \frac1m\Leftrightarrow 0\leq 1$.

So $-1$ is indeed a lower bound.

> Why is $-1$ the greatest lower bound of $A$?

Suppose there is a lower bound $b$ of $A$ with $b>-1$. Then we can write $b=-1+\varepsilon$ for some fixed $\varepsilon >0$.

$b$ is supposed to be a lower bound, so

$-1+\varepsilon\leq a$ for every $a\in A$. For arbitrary $n=2m+1$ we have:

$-1+\varepsilon\leq -1+\frac{1}{2m+1}\Leftrightarrow \varepsilon\leq \frac{1}{2m+1}$ for every $m\in\mathbb{N}$!

But then $2m+1\leq \frac1\varepsilon$ for every $m\in\mathbb{N}$, which is false, since the LHS is unbounded. (For every real number there is a natural number greater then that.)

Answer (score 1):

By following your steps,

- you made a small mistake in step 1: you proved that for all $n$ **even** elements of $A$ are greater than $-1$. For $n$ odd you have to prove that $-1+\frac{1}{2n+1}>-1$, but that is pretty simple, so you might have omitted it because it's trivial.
- for step 2: given any $\epsilon>0$ you can find elements of $A$ which are smaller than $-1+\epsilon$: take $n$ odd, so we look only at elements of the type $-1+\frac{1}{2n+1}$.Now you can always choose $n$ large enough so that $\frac{1}{2n+1} < \epsilon$, for instance take any $n>\frac{1}{2\epsilon}-\frac{1}{2}$. Thus proving that, for any $\epsilon>0$, $-1+\epsilon$ cannot be the $\inf$.

The trick here is to separate $A$ into two subsets: $A_{even}=\{1-\frac{1}{2n}, n=1,2,...\}$ and $A_{odd}=\{-1+\frac{1}{2n+1}, n=1,2,...\}$. You clearly have that $A$ is the union of these two, therefore the inf of $A$ is the smallest of the infs of $A_{odd}$ and $A_{even}$.

I hope it clears it up :)

Comment: WOW . Perfect explanation